# blob data to xml data type

Tags: java, xml, blob, special-characters

i have a below format of blob data type in my oracle database

```
2007340ýDþ2007346ýDþ2007353ýDþ2007360ýDþ2008002ýDþ2008009ýDþ2008016ýA
```

i need to write to a file into a XML data type. Below is the format which i need in xml

```
<row xml:space='preserve'><c1>2007340</c1><c2>2007346</c2><c3>2007353</c3><c4>2007360</c4><c5>2008002</c5></row>
```

i want to escape the characters like "ýDþ" which is called as a field marker in oracle.

After escaping i have to write with  tag.

Kindly advice me how to do this..

Answer (score 0):

If by tags you mean the unicode codes for non-standard characters use this website: http://graphemica.com/ However I am not sure if that's what you're asking about...